# Concatenating inner text in an XPath array

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <instructions type="array">
    <item type="string">Cannot do business directly with consumers</item>
    <item type="string">Cannot marry a martian</item>
  </instructions>
</root>
```

and an `instructions` variable that looks like this:

```
var instructions = myXDocument.XPathSelectElements("/root/instructions").Nodes();
```

I am attempting to concatenate all of the `item` strings, thusly:

> "Cannot do business directly with consumers, Cannot marry a martian"

and my attempt so far is

```
instructions.Select(x => x.[[What do I put here?]]).Aggregate((i,j) => i + ", " + j)
```

but having trouble figuring out how to get the inner text from each node in my lambda expression.  `x.ToString()` yields `"<item type="string">Cannot do business directly with consumers</item>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach, you can simply replace `Nodes()` with `Elements()`, and then access the `Value` property of the returned `XElements` to get the inner texts :

```
var instructions = myXDocument.XPathSelectElements("/root/instructions").Elements();
var result = instructions.Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((i,j) => i + ", " + j);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the lambda expression which you are looking for but this is way around to get the resultant output.

```
string result;
XElement root = XElement.Load(SomeXML);
root.Element("root").Elements("instructions").Elements("item").All<XElement>(xe =>
{
    result = result + xe.Attribute("type").Value),
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var xml = "<root><instructions type=\"array\"><item type=\"string\">Cannot do business directly with consumers</item><item type=\"string\">Cannot marry a martian</item></instructions></root>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = string.Join(", ", document.Descendants("instructions").Elements("item").Select(x=>x.Value));
```

Output:

> Cannot do business directly with consumers, Cannot marry a martian